# Node js doesn't wait to finish process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have simple Node js script that read a csv file and push data in array.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log("Done");
  });

  console.log(results[10])
```

I would like node first read whole of csv and next print array.
Any solution?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837132/how-to-wait-for-a-stream-to-finish-piping-nodejs answers your question

Comment: You need to print the `results` array inside `.on('end')` because that is the only place that executes code at the end of stream processing

Comment: Put the `console.log(results)` into `end` callback function.